'Activity' tab Not displaying in SonarCloud
I have both admin and owner permissions, but I'm unable to see the Activity tab in our project. We have run analyses on future branches, but the Activity tab does not display.
Could you please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Any assistance you can offer would be appreciated.
See screenshot.
The project overview page shows this: 'master branch has not been analyzed yet.'
Another screenshot
I deleted the first projects I setup and rerun a new analysis but it didn't change. I cleared my browser and it came back same without the 'Activity' tab.
